# Proof that $\sum_{d|m} |\mu(d)|=2^n$, where $n$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-sum, mobius-function

Given an integer $m$ such that $n$ is denoting the **distinct** prime divisors of $m$, is there a proof that the sum over the divisors of m of the absolute value of the Möbius function $\mu(d)$ is equal to

\begin{equation}
\sum_{d|m} \left|\mu(d)\right|=2^n,
\end{equation}

where the Möbius function is defined as
\begin{equation}
 %\small
\mu(d) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
   1  &  \text{if $d = 1$} \\
   (-1)^k & \text{if $d$ is the product of $k$ distinct primes} \\
   0   & \text{if $d$ has one or more repeated prime factors}\,.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

I checked the relation in Maple empirically and it seems to be correct, however I could not come up with a formal proof for this result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|\mu(d)|$ is non-zero and equal to one when $d$ is a product of primes, i.e. there is a bijection between those $d$ and the subsets of the set of prime divisors of $m$. There are precisely $2^n$ of these, done.

Answer (score 2):

Denoting the distinct prime factors of $m$ as $p_1, \cdots, p_n$:
$ \sum_{d|m} \lvert \mu(d)\rvert  = \lvert \mu(1)\rvert + \sum_i \lvert \mu(p_i)\rvert + \sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n} \lvert \mu(p_i p_j) \rvert + \cdots + \lvert \mu(p_1 p_2\cdots p_n)\rvert $
$= 1 + \binom{n}{1} 1 + \binom{n}{2} 1^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}1^n  $

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Outline: The function given by the sum on the left is *multiplicative*. So basically you only need to verify that the equality holds for prime powers.